# Unable to make POST request HTTPS server via axios in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, post, axios, cors, nuxt.js

When in NuxtJS, I am trying to make a POST request to a HTTPS server via axios and I have it deployed via Vercel. It is not getting the content from the POST request.

Current Code:

```
<script>
import LoadingWheel from '@/components/LoadingWheel.vue'
export default {
    components: { LoadingWheel },
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                question: '',
                submitCounter: 0
            },
            answer: null,
            loading: false,
            typedAnswer: '',
            urls: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.form.submitCounter = 0
        }, 3600000)
    },
    methods: {
        resetForm() {
            this.form.question = ''
            this.answer = null
            this.loading = false
            this.typedAnswer = ''
            this.urls = null
        },
        async submitForm() {
            this.form.submitCounter++
            this.loading = true
            try {
                const { data } = await this.$axios.post(
                    'https://internet-ml-backend.paas.thamognya.com/api/nlp/no-context/question-answering/',
                    {
                        question: this.form.question
                    }
                )
                this.tmpquestion = this.form.question
                this.resetForm()
                this.answer = data.response.answer
                const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    this.typedAnswer +=
                        this.answer[this.typedAnswer.length] || ''
                    if (this.typedAnswer.length === this.answer.length) {
                        clearInterval(typingInterval)
                    }
                }, 150)
                this.urls = data.resources
            } catch (error) {
                // console.error(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It works locally (i.e running both backend and frontend locally) and additionally I can make POST requests to the server. Generally it should make the POST request and then finish the loading screen and then show / print the answer to the screen.

logs that come up after I make the POST request: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing and then NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI.

Comment: What is the response from the server? Can you check the browser logs (e.g. chrome network tab) and give some more info? If it works locally, it could be that it isn't a code issue but might be something like e.g. wrongly configured CORS headers

Comment: Here are the logs that come up after I make the POST request: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing and then NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI.

Comment: @Thamognya In your backend, set `origin: "*"` in your cors config. This allows your frontend to make requests to ur backend.

Comment: Have you configured the server for CORS? If so, edit your question and add your CORS configuration.